# Passing in Oracle custom user types from Python/Django

Tags: python, django, cx-oracle

Lets say I have the following my_type and my_type_tab as custom user types in oracle -

```
CREATE type my_type as object(
name   varchar2(30)
,key    varchar2(100)
,value   varchar2(4000))
/
CREATE type my_type_tab as table of my_type
/
```

And then a procedure utilizing these types as follows:

```
PROCEDURE my_procedure (param  in  my_type_tab);
```

Is there any way to construct the my_type_tab in Python/Django and pass it into my_procedure? In my scenario, I could have one or hundreds of the my_type rows and this would be by far the easiest way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about declaring a python class that represents `my_type`:

```
# python representation of my_type
class my_type(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, key):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.key = key
```

Creating a list of those:

```
# Create my_type python objects
my_list = [my_type('a', '1', 'x'),
           my_type('b', '2', 'y'),
           my_type('c', '3', 'z'),
           ]
```

And generating a query to run them like this:

```
# Run my_package.my_procedure() over my_list
cursor.execute("""
    declare
        l_params my_type_tab;
        type varchar_list is table of varchar2(4000) index by binary_integer;
        l_names varchar_list := :p_names;
        l_keys varchar_list := :p_keys;
        l_values varchar_list := :p_values;
    begin
        l_params.extend(l_names.count);
        for i in 1..l_names.count loop
            l_params(i) := my_type(l_names(i), l_keys(i), l_values(i));
        end loop;

        my_package.my_procedure(l_params);
    end;""",
    p_names=[item.name for item in my_list],
    p_values=[item.value for item in my_list],
    p_keys=[item.key for item in my_list],
    )
```

If you're interested, I could generalise this to any type, not just `my_type`.

Comment: I actually figured this out yesterday but a little dirtier than you have. I was doing basically this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/976322/1415307

Thank you, this is a much cleaner way to do it.